# How to map api nodes with nginx location?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to run node app on nginx.

Here is my nginx configuration.

```
location /first {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

And here is node app router.

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
```

But when I access server via x.x.x.x/first I get 404 errors. What is the reason. Please let me know if you know.

Comment: Is this your whole nginx configuration? Are you able to share the configuration of the server block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because of your locations configuration on the NGINX side.

So based on what I guess you want to do:

```
/first/ -> Node Index Route
/first/api -> Node API Route
```

This would result in the following configuration

```
server {

  ....


  location /first {
    rewrite ^/first(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000
    ....
  }

}
```